# Maximum value of a product of type $(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I wish to calculate the maximum value of the product $(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n)$ where $x$ lies in the interval $[x_0,x_n]$. I know to apply the AM-GM inequality to get
$$(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n) \le \left(\frac{(x-x_0)+(x-x_1)+\cdots+(x-x_n)}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$

However, how do I find at what $x\;\epsilon\;[x_0,x_n]$ this RHS becomes maximum? Since this is mostly a long product, I do not have the option of differentiating and finding the roots. Or is there any different method?

**Edit:** The absolute value of the product is to be considered. So I guess, I need to find the maximum or minimum value of the product in the given interval. I did not notice that I needed to consider absolute values, sorry about that. I need the maximum value of $$|(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n)|\;\;\;\;x\;\epsilon\;[x_0,x_n]$$

If it helps, I noticed that for $|(x-x_0)(x-x_1)|$, the maximum value in the given interval occurs at $x=\cfrac{x_0+x_1}{2}$ and hence, the maximum value of the product is given as $$|(x-x_0)(x-x_1)|\le\cfrac{(x_1-x_0)^2}{4}$$
Can this be extended to more terms in the product in any way?

Comment: The OP (vaguely) implies that $x_n \geq x_0$. Is that true? In general is true that $x_i \geq x_{i-1}$?

Comment: You may consider that to be true.

Comment: just a thought, could the rearrangement inequality help?

Comment: 1) May I ask where you found this problem? 2) Did you really intend to add the linear algebra tag? Do you expect the problem to have a solution using linear algebra?

Comment: @mickep I faced this problem in error analysis. In finding the bound of the error, I need to find the maximum value of that given product. Also, I do not know whether it can be solved using linear algebra, but a method in that direction is acceptable too.

Comment: Here's an extension to three terms with $0,x_1,x_2$. (Setting $x_0>0$ just translates the graph to the right.) $\frac{\left(x_1+x_2\pm\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2-x_1x_2}\right)}{3}$. The two solutions correspond to the two maxima between $x_0,x_1$ and $x_1,x_2$. I'm going to go out on a limb and conjecture that with 4 terms, the maxima will be given by a cubic equation, with 5 a quartic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply AM-GM inequality on numbers, say, $a_1,a_2,a_3 \dots a_n$; then AM$=$GM iff $$a_1=a_2=a_3=\dots =a_n$$

But unfortunately, $x-x_i=x-x_j$, results only if $x_i=x_j ~ ;~\forall i,j \in \{0,1,2 \dots n\}$, which is not (probably) the case here. Hence, derivatives is the only possible way to determine the maximum value of product.